# How to assign column value based on index substring?

Tags: pandas, numpy

If the index ends with "01-09"A, label it as "tumor" in the "type" column.
If the index ends with "10-19"A, label it as "normal" in the "type" column.
The column name is multi-index.
How do I assign the "type" column accordingly?

```
# 01-09 : tumor
# 10-19 : normal

meth_450_5_kipan = meth_450_5_kipan.assign(type=(
    meth_450_5_kipan.index
    .str.split('-')
    .str[-1]
    .str.contains(r'0[1-9]', regex=True)
)).replace({'type':{True:"tumor", False:"normal"}}).dropna(axis=1)
```

Current output:

`meth_450_5_kipan.iloc[-5:,-5:]`

```
pd.DataFrame({('cg09560763', 'PRDM8'): {'TCGA-Y8-A898-01A': 0.505822845732314,
  'TCGA-Y8-A8RY-01A': 0.494413413161009,
  'TCGA-Y8-A8RZ-11A': 0.301740989582562,
  'TCGA-Y8-A8S0-01A': 0.235758339404136,
  'TCGA-Y8-A8S1-01A': 0.731030638674928},
 ('cg09560811', nan): {'TCGA-Y8-A898-01A': 0.933102042099432,
  'TCGA-Y8-A8RY-01A': 0.9097565027488,
  'TCGA-Y8-A8RZ-11A': 0.920238344141844,
  'TCGA-Y8-A8S0-01A': 0.924803871437567,
  'TCGA-Y8-A8S1-01A': 0.929761655129724},
 ('cg09560911', 'TNFRSF21'): {'TCGA-Y8-A898-01A': 0.0262547882636862,
  'TCGA-Y8-A8RY-01A': 0.031638387180189,
  'TCGA-Y8-A8RZ-11A': 0.0304795189432937,
  'TCGA-Y8-A8S0-01A': 0.0255867247450433,
  'TCGA-Y8-A8S1-01A': 0.0234602952079715},
 ('cg09560953', 'UBE2E1'): {'TCGA-Y8-A898-01A': 0.901422948355672,
  'TCGA-Y8-A8RY-01A': 0.851164164393655,
  'TCGA-Y8-A8RZ-11A': 0.707673764192998,
  'TCGA-Y8-A8S0-01A': 0.721923173082175,
  'TCGA-Y8-A8S1-01A': 0.835676721188431},
 ('type', ''): {'TCGA-Y8-A898-01A': True,
  'TCGA-Y8-A8RY-01A': True,
  'TCGA-Y8-A8RZ-11': False,
  'TCGA-Y8-A8S0-01A': True,
  'TCGA-Y8-A8S1-01A': True}}
```

Expected output:

```
{('cg09560763', 'PRDM8'): {'TCGA-Y8-A898-01A': 0.505822845732314,
  'TCGA-Y8-A8RY-01A': 0.494413413161009,
  'TCGA-Y8-A8RZ-11A': 0.301740989582562,
  'TCGA-Y8-A8S0-01A': 0.235758339404136,
  'TCGA-Y8-A8S1-01A': 0.731030638674928},
 ('cg09560811', nan): {'TCGA-Y8-A898-01A': 0.933102042099432,
  'TCGA-Y8-A8RY-01A': 0.9097565027488,
  'TCGA-Y8-A8RZ-11A': 0.920238344141844,
  'TCGA-Y8-A8S0-01A': 0.924803871437567,
  'TCGA-Y8-A8S1-01A': 0.929761655129724},
 ('cg09560911', 'TNFRSF21'): {'TCGA-Y8-A898-01A': 0.0262547882636862,
  'TCGA-Y8-A8RY-01A': 0.031638387180189,
  'TCGA-Y8-A8RZ-11A': 0.0304795189432937,
  'TCGA-Y8-A8S0-01A': 0.0255867247450433,
  'TCGA-Y8-A8S1-01A': 0.0234602952079715},
 ('cg09560953', 'UBE2E1'): {'TCGA-Y8-A898-01A': 0.901422948355672,
  'TCGA-Y8-A8RY-01A': 0.851164164393655,
  'TCGA-Y8-A8RZ-11A': 0.707673764192998,
  'TCGA-Y8-A8S0-01A': 0.721923173082175,
  'TCGA-Y8-A8S1-01A': 0.835676721188431},
 ('type', ''): {'TCGA-Y8-A898-01A': True,
  'TCGA-Y8-A8RY-01A': tumor,
  'TCGA-Y8-A8RZ-11': normal,
  'TCGA-Y8-A8S0-01A': tumor,
  'TCGA-Y8-A8S1-01A': tumor}})
```

Comment: What exactly are you working with here?  You have a `numpy` and `pandas`  tags, but your examples are `dict` and `tuples` (or even JSON).

Comment: I generated the dataframe using `numpy` and `pandas`. I printed the example as `dict` but amended it so that people can try it as a dataframe.

Comment: Typo? `.replace({('type',''):{True:"tumor", False:"normal"}})` Your column header is `('type','')`, not just `'type'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you've provided does not run correctly. This is because the .str.contains() method returns a boolean series, and the .replace() method is used for replacing values in a dataframe not for creating new columns.

Here is possible approach that will accomplish what you're trying to do:

```
meth_450_5_kipan['type'] = meth_450_5_kipan.index.str.split('-').str[-1].str.contains(r'0[1-9]', regex=True)
meth_450_5_kipan['type'] = meth_450_5_kipan['type'].replace({True: "tumor", False: "normal"})
meth_450_5_kipan = meth_450_5_kipan.dropna(axis=1)
```

This code creates a new column `'type'` in the dataframe by using the `.str.contains()` method on the index. Then replace boolean values by tumor and normal using the replace method. Finally, drop the columns with NaN values using `dropna()`.

This should create a new `'type'` column in the dataframe with the desired values, and drop the columns with NaN values.